WooCommerce custom add to cart with quantity buttons
I need to set up a custom add to cart button with the product ID added.
This is the code I have and it works perfectly.

function custom_add_to_cart_button_with_quantity_shortcode($atts) {
   
    $product_id = isset($atts['product_id']) ? intval($atts['product_id']) : null;

    if ($product_id) {
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" method="post" class="cart">
            <div class="quantity">
                <input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
                <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
                <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Buy Now</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr($product_id); ?>">
        </form>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".plus").click(function() {
                    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name="quantity"]').val());
                    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                        $('input[name="quantity"]').val(currentVal + 1);
                    }
                });
                $(".minus").click(function() {
                    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name="quantity"]').val());
                    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
                        $('input[name="quantity"]').val(currentVal - 1);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        return 'ID del prodotto non valido.';
    }
}
add_shortcode('custom_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_add_to_cart_button_with_quantity_shortcode');

The problem comes when I add two buttons, for two products, on the same page.
The quantity increment goes by two (1 - 3 - 5)
How can I solve this problem?`

$('input[name="quantity"]').val() will only ever get you the value of the first element in the document, that matches this selector. You need to select the correct element(s), based on context. From the clicked +/- button, go up to the form element using https://api.jquery.com/parents/, and then use find to select your quantity input field within the context of that form.

It's not very clear to me how to solve this problem

Inside your click handler functions, $(this) gives you access to the clicked element. So call the parents method on that, to navigate up to the form - $(this).parents('form'). And then call .find() on that to select your quantity input field within that form.
